# Exercise in Simplicial Homology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

In *Basic Concepts of Algebraic Topology* by Fred Croom, the homology groups of the $n$-skeleton of the closure of an $(n+1)$-simplex are computed in Theorem 2.9. (The geometric carrier of the complex is homeomorphic to the $n$-sphere).

Exercise 21 at the end of the chapter (Chapter 2) asks one to show that the
homology groups of positive dimension of the closure of a simplex are trivial and thus deduce that the homology groups of the $n$-sphere are trivial in dimensions $1,2,...,n-1$.

I'm not sure what the author has in mind for this exercise. Of course, the simplex is contractible (whereas the sphere is not), but the concept of homotopy has not yet been introduced. With the exception of the homology group of dimension equal to that of the simplex, it seems to me that solving the exercise amounts to repeating the computations in Theorem 2.9.

Comment: What does "closure" of a simplex mean here?

Comment: @fermesomme It means the complex that consists of all faces of the simplex.

Comment: It is a bit strange since the author hasn't introduced homology groups, so I'm not sure what he's asking. Probably to repeat the computations in the theorem. To calculate the singular homology groups of a sphere, there are a couple of different ways. One is to make use of exact sequences of $(S^n, D^{n+})$, another uses Mayer-Vietoris and induction.

Comment: @fermesomme Only the homology groups of a simplicial complex have been introduced.